Does serial data type assign unique values to each thread trying to insert?
I am getting following error when inserting data in Postgres in a multi-threaded env, I am relying of serial data type to assign PK assuming it is thread-safe, I lose data when I get following error, how can ensure that each thread gets unique-id? I am using plain java. i.e java.sql library to perform error:
`org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "pg_class_relname_nsp_index"
  Detail: Key (relname, relnamespace)=(table_id_seq, 2200) already exists.`

I am using the followng query to insert entries in table
"insert into "+ MODEL_TABLE +" (b,c,d) values(?,?,?);";

the following query for creating the table
CREATE_MODEL_TABLE =
            "CREATE TABLE if not exists "+ MODEL_TABLE +"(\n" +
            "    id SERIAL,\n" +
            "    a int,\n" +
            "    b int,\n" +
            "    c int,\n" +
            "    PRIMARY KEY (id,b),\n" +
            "  constraint unique_name_%s unique(b,c)"+
            ") PARTITION BY LIST (b);";


The error is coming from the system catalog pg_class on it's index pg_class_relname_nsp_index" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (relname, relnamespace). That would indicate to me your code is trying to creating multiple copies of the sequence(table_id_seq) itself.  You need to add the actual Java code you are using. Best guess is you are creating the table in concurrent threads.

Always report the Postgres version in use. Maybe this is an outdated (point-) release.

@AdrianKlaver, yes I am trying to create table using concurrent threads!!
Will take care of that. thanks

Assuming you using the Postgres JDBC Driver then from here Multithreaded: The PostgreSQL® JDBC driver is not thread safe

pg_class_relname_nsp_index is the name of a UNIQUE index in the system catalog pg_class, where every table-like object (incl. sequences) is registered. Table + schema name must be unique. Hence the unique index pg_class_relname_nsp_index ON pg_class(relname, relnamespace).
The error is not raised by inserting into your user table, but during creation of the table. The serial column triggers the creation of an underlying SEQUENCE. See:

How to convert primary key from integer to serial?
Auto increment table column

The error really makes no sense. For a serial column, Postgres would avoid using a duplicate sequence name and pick the next free name automatically instead of running into a unique violation. ("table_id_seq1" etc.)
Even if you try to create a sequence with an occupied name manually, you'd get a different error message.
Hence I suspect index corruption.
To fix, run (with the necessary privileges!):
REINDEX TABLE pg_class;

This should not occur to begin with. I have never seen this error message in my long Postgres life. Failing hardware comes to mind. If you don't have a recent backup, now is the time!

the above error is incomplete. is you answer still same if the error is the following one?
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "pg_class_relname_nsp_index"   Detail: Key (relname, relnamespace)=(elo_score_ds_nn_model_id_seq, 2200) already exists.

I am getting error ocasionally though not every time

Still the same. But please make it a habit to post the complete, literal error msg in questions, along with the Postgres version in use.
